# How to fingerprint a server with Netcat?

Tags: fingerprinting, information-gathering, netcat

I am trying to follow the OWASP test guide on a Kali Linux machine. As the first step in "Information Gathering" I am trying to fingerprint the server. The guide instructs me to use NetCat:

```
$ nc www.xxx.yy 80
```

But after several attempts I always get this result:

```
$ nc www.xxx.yy 80  
DNS fwd/rev ..............  
www.xxx.yy [IP] 80 (http) open
```

Instead when I use

```
$ whatweb www.xxx.yy
```

I was able to retrieve a lots of information, including:

```
HTTP Headers:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK     
Date: ***  
Server: Apache  
X-Powered-By: ******
```

Where is the error in my way to use Netcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to open a connection to the target on port 80. You also need to perform an HTTP request like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

and ideally send a user-agent...

Comment: Thanks using _printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc ww.xxx.yy 80_ it works!